# lazy loading a weak instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, lazy-loading

I want to lazy load a instance variable - but if it is set from outside the class I don't want to strongly point to it.

Is this possible?

for instance:

```
@interface MyClass

@property (nonatomic,weak) LazyLoadedObject lazyObject;
@end

@implemetation MyClass

-(LazyLoadedObject *)lazyObject
{
  if (_lazyObject== nil)
  {
    //create a object and strongly point to it
    _lazyObject = [LazyLoadedObject new]
  }
  return _lazyObject;
}
@end
```

Comment: You need to designate who owns the object - the owner needs to retain it. Does this class own it or not. Decide one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **another property** for your private to which you will have strong reference, if needed.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id lazyObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id privateLazyObject;
```

Then implement getters like this:

```
- (id)lazyObject {
    // If contains value, return that, otherwise redirect to private strong value.
    return self->_lazyObject ?: self.privateLazyObject;
}

- (id)privateLazyObject {
    // Standard lazy getter
    if ( ! self->_privateLazyObject) {
        self.privateLazyObject = ...; // Strong ownership
    }
    return self->_privateLazyObject;
}
```

So when you set the public `lazyObject`, nullify your private one:

```
- (void)setLazyObject:(id)lazyObject {
    self->_lazyObject = lazyObject; // Weak ownership
    self.privateLazyObject = nil; // Release any existing strong one.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the property `strong`, since you want to "strongly point to it".